# google app engine: url not found on this server/404 error

Tags: google-app-engine

I have code cloned from GitHub Zorya. I just added a `www` folder and an `index.html` file in it as I read somewhere that error was because there was no `www` directory.

Here's how my app structure looks like:

[image]

My app.yaml file:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: default

builtins:
- deferred: on

# Handlers define how to route requests to your application.
 handlers:
 - url: /api/v1/(.*)
  script: main.app

 - url: /tasks/(.*) 
 script: main.app

- url: /
 static_files: build/index.html
 upload: build/index.html

- url: /favicon\.png
 static_files: build/favicon.png
 upload: build/favicon\.png

# unused for now
# - url: /service-worker\.js
#   static_files: build/service-worker.js
#   upload: build/service-worker\.js

 - url: /manifest\.json
  static_files: build/manifest.json
  upload: build/manifest\.json

 - url: /static/(.*)
 static_files: build/static/\1
 upload: build/static/(.*)

 - url: .*
 static_files: build/index.html
 upload: build/index.html


  # here if you want to use them.  See
 # https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27 for
# a list of libraries included in the SDK.  Third party libs that are *not* 
part
# of the App Engine SDK don't need to be listed here, instead add them to 
your
 # project directory, either as a git submodule or as a plain subdirectory.
#libraries:
#- name: jinja2
  #  version: latest

 libraries:
- name: ssl
  version: latest
 - name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"

 skip_files:
 - ^\.git$
  - ^\client$
  - ^\venv$

 # needed for dev_appserver.py, tracks too many changes otherwise
- .*/zorya/client
```

Here's one of the errors that I see in the logs :

[image]

Comment: what is the path requested? you should see it in the logs

Comment: W  GET 404 0 B 0 ms Chrome 71 /favicon.ico GET 404 0 B 0 ms Chrome 71 5c28b32600ff0a7005cd19916600016e7e766d2d7363686564756c61720001323031383132333074313730343139000100
  2405:204:9126:ca51:b512:7e2e:573a:3af6 - - [30/Dec/2018:17:29:34 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 - - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36" "vm-schedular.appspot.com" ms=0 cpu_ms=0 cpm_usd=0 loading_request=0 instance=- app_engine_release=1.9.65 trace_id=-

Answer (score 0):

Your requests for `/favicon.ico` (shown in the comment log) and for `/` (from the logs image) both match the `.*` handler pattern, for which you have configured serving a `build/index.html` static resource.

But you don't have a `build` directory under the `zorya` app/service directory, so your static resource doesn't exist. Hence the 404 error.

Maybe you mean to use `www` instead of `build`? If so you should match the name of the directory with the one used in the handler pattern. You could just rename the `www` directory to `build` (no, you don't **need** to use that exact name).

In particular for the favicon error, you may want to specify a handler for `favicon.ico` instead of `favicon.png`